# How to stack Transfer Learning models in a Sequential

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

To make a nice architecture, I wanted to stack Transfer Learning models one over the other.

The three models I wanted to stack were :

- VGG16
- InceptionV3
- Resnet50

So, I defined the three models as follows :

```
model_vgg = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
    weights='imagenet', 
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3)
)

model_inc = tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3(
    weights='imagenet', 
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3)
)

model_res = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    weights='imagenet', 
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3)
)
```

> Size was set as 100

After this, I set `trainable=False` for each one of them

Now, how would I stack these models in a sequential i.e what changes will I have to make so that the output shape for each model matches the input shape for the next ?

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    
    model_vgg,
    model_inc,
    model_res,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
    
])
```

Comment: Do you want to use the output of `model_vgg` as the input of `model_inc` etc.?

Comment: @AloneTogether Yes

Comment: you cant do that, each model you have expects an image. Each model has a different architecture and output shape which is not equal to image size. you have to make a new model that has the required output shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each model has a different output shape, you will have to reshape each one before feeding it to the next model and this will probably impact the performance:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

SIZE = 100
model_vgg = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
    weights='imagenet', 
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3)
)

model_inc = tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3(
    weights='imagenet', 
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3)
)

model_res = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    weights='imagenet', 
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3)
)

model_vgg.trainable = False
model_inc.trainable = False
model_res.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    
    model_vgg,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(SIZE*SIZE*3),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((SIZE, SIZE, 3)),
    model_inc,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(SIZE*SIZE*3),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((SIZE, SIZE, 3)),
    model_res,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
    
])
print(model(tf.random.normal((1, 100, 100, 3))).shape)
```

You will also have to decide if you want to use a nonlinear activation function on each `Dense` layer. Oh, and you could also use the preprocessing methods of each model like this:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x)),
    model_vgg,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(SIZE*SIZE*3),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((SIZE, SIZE, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input(x)),
    model_inc,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(SIZE*SIZE*3),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((SIZE, SIZE, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(x)),
    model_res,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
    
])
```

My personal suggestion would be to feed the inputs into the individual models and then concatenate the outputs and run other downstream operations:

```py
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((SIZE, SIZE, 3))
    
vgg = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x))(inputs)
vgg = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool2D()(model_vgg(vgg))

inc = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input(x))(inputs)
inc = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool2D()(model_inc(inc))

res = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(x))(inputs)
res = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool2D()(model_res(res))

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([vgg, inc, res])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Comment: This worked ! But is this model too heavy to train ? I'm getting resource allocation errors onmy first epoch

Comment: It depends on your hardware and batch size you are using. Hard to say though.